# ASCII characters converted to 2 hexagonal numbers

Tags: character, ascii

Could someone tell me why characters from extended ASCII table are being converted to 2 hexagonal numbers instead of 1? For example:
a = 61
â = C3 A2 (even though it should be normally encoded as E2)

Comment: Is there something I don't understand? Why extended ASCII characters are converted to 2 hex when Stanard ASCII characters converts to only 1?

Comment: No idea what you are talking about...what language, what cases ....

Comment: No particular language. For example on this site: http://www.swingnote.com/tools/texttohex.php and many others converting â to hexadecimal will give C3 A2, but in the ASCII table it's encoded as E2. And I don't really understand why.

Comment: *hexagonal numbers* don't exist. Did you mean hexadecimal ?

Comment: Ow. Yes I did. Idk what I meant -_- Sorry for the confusion

Comment: 1) There is no _one_  Extended ASCII, and when which you say which one, there almost never any need to describe it as Extended ASCII. 2) You have to consider if any Extended ASCII actually is normal in your situation. UTF-8 is the normal in many, many situations for storing and transmitting text (including this web page). UTF-8 is one of several character encodings for the Unicode character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "Hex UTF-8 bytes".

U+007F (127) -> 1 Byte

U+07FF (2,047) -> 2 Byte

http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%C3%A2&mode=char
http://unicode.mayastudios.com/examples/utf8.html

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I have been struggling with.